# notifyDataSetChanged() is not calling onBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When i call notifyDataSetChanged() it doesn't call my onBindViewHolder and i have no idea why it does this, i am currely using a custom layout and don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Anybody have any ideas? here is the code is the peace of code I use to call the datasetchange within my adapter.

```
public void updateFriendsCheckinData(HashMap<Integer, List<LiveCheckin>>  updatedCheckinMap){
        this.friendCheckinMap = updatedCheckinMap;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public void updateFriendsCheckinData(HashMap<Integer, List<LiveCheckin>> updatedCheckinMap) {
    // here we are clearing existing data in the HashMap
    friendCheckinMap.clear();

    friendCheckinMap = updatedCheckinMap;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And then in your getItemCount() method we have:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    // if you are using the data in the list retrieved from the hashmap, then here return the size of the list instead.
    return friendCheckinMap.size();
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

You've to call notifydatasetchanged in onClick events instead of OnBindviewHolder.

if you call on OnBindviewHolder it might crash due to recyclerview populating views.

Here is the samplecode

```
 @Override
public void onRecyclerViewItemClick(@NonNull View view, @NonNull AndroidVersion calendarDTO, int position) {

    Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```